# oracle control file and undo databasefile was deleted,Is there a way to get back？

Tags: oracle

Recreate control file,this is the code

```
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "ORCL" RESETLOGS NOARCHIVELOG
 MAXLOGFILES 5
 MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
 MAXDATAFILES 100
 MAXINSTANCES 1
 MAXLOGHISTORY 226
LOGFILE
  GROUP 1 '/home/oracle/app/oradata/orcl/redo01.log' SIZE 50M,
  GROUP 2 '/home/oracle/app/oradata/orcl/redo02.log' SIZE 50M,
  GROUP 3 '/home/oracle/app/oradata/orcl/redo03.log' SIZE 50M
DATAFILE
  '/home/oracle/app/oradata/orcl/osc_zb.dbf',
  ......
CHARACTER SET ZHS16GBK;
```

After then open database,the result is as follows:

```
ORA-01194: file 1 needs more recovery to be consistent
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/home/oracle/app/oradata/orcl/system01.dbf'
```

recover datafile 1:

```
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-16433: The database must be opened in read/write mode.
```

then,use hidden parameters to start database.

```
undo_management='manual' 
undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS01'
_allow_resetlogs_corruption=true
```

also don't work:

```
SQL> startup pfile=/home/oracle/initoracle.ora
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1586708480 bytes
Fixed Size          2253624 bytes
Variable Size         973081800 bytes
Database Buffers      603979776 bytes
Redo Buffers            7393280 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01113: file 1 needs media recovery
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/home/oracle/app/oradata/orcl/system01.dbf'
```

Such a cycle

```
SQL> recover datafile 1
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-16433: The database must be opened in read/write mode.
```

I hava no idea to restore database,moguls,help me

Answer (score 0):

Can start to mounted status?Maybe You can try following method。
first,find the 'CURRENT' redo groups.

```
select group#,sequence#,status,first_time,next_change# from v$log;
```

And find the redo file location

```
select * from v$logfile;
```

Then,through this redo log to recover database

```
SQL> recover database until cancel using backup controlfile;
ORA-00279: change 4900911271334 generated at 03/06/2018 05:46:29 needed for
thread 1
ORA-00289: suggestion :
/home/wonders/app/wonders/flash_recovery_area/ORCL/archivelog/2018_03_12/o1_mf_1
_4252_%u_.arc
ORA-00280: change 4900911271334 for thread 1 is in sequence #4252
Specify log: {<RET>=suggested | filename | AUTO | CANCEL}
/home/wonders/app/wonders/oradata/orcl/redo01.log
Log applied.
Media recovery complete.
```

Finally,open database with ‘RESETLOGS’

Comment: I've tried it too，it's not work，when alter database open with ‘RESETLOGS’，oracle will be force close，maybe lost undo file